# Display Smartphone Screen on TV

Tags: tv-out

Could anybody suggest a way to display my smartphone's screen, as we use it, on a TV monitor, possiblly via a S-Video connector

Comment: Please specify your phone.

Comment: I use a Nokia C6-00 Symbian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the Phone. My Galaxy Nexus supports HDMI out via the usb port (It's called MHL, there are adapters for under $15 on dx.com). Your not going to get S-Video without some kind of converter though.

Comment: Does that HDMI out mean I will get the screen as such on the HDMI or just a video or photo that we see?

Comment: It gives me the full screen. There is also a VGA one. If you really wanted you could try daisy chaining a VGA->S-Video adapter aswell (not sure if it would work or not).

Comment: David, so if I'm, say, using Google Map on the phone, do I get it on the TV as well?

Comment: Yep. Should show everything on the screen (although limited to landscape mode).